# Quick reshaping of table in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, data-analysis

I'm new to using Excel/DAX.

Just wondering if there would be a quicker way to format the table

[image: Table 1]

What I'm trying to achieve, is getting the above table to be formatted the same as below

[image: Table 2]

Notice how in the lower table there is only 1 column for the year. I understand that this creates duplications of the countries in the first column

Any advice would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Load the table into **PowerQuery**
2. Select the first 2 columns
3. In the **Transform tab** select from **Unpivot other columns**
4. There you go!

Btw, it's a typical ETL step (hence PowerQuery) called *stacking* a table from *wide* to *long*.